# In c#, is it a good practice to return default literal?

Tags: c#, return-value, default-value, return-type

Recently, I saw some are writing code to return default literal for nullable primitive type, is there a real benefit for it?

To make it simple,

```
int? TestDefault(int input)
{
    if (input > 10)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

In the code above, it return default (it is `null` for type `int?`)

It looks good at the 1st glance.

But the problem is that when the return type of the function is changed from `int?` to `int`, it will return 0, which may be unintentional (sometimes, the magic number may be a negative number instead of 0) and easily gets ignored by the one who changes it (because there is no compile error and 0 seems making sense) especially when the one is changing a lot of long and complex methods.

Indeed, for default literals, they are 0/false/null. All of them are of less letters than default. What is the reason we use the `default` literal here? By specifying 0/false/null explicitly, it makes clearer that what is the value it is expecting.

Comment: Changing a return type is a breaking change anyway, so there will likely be some refactoring required in either case. If anything, the only change I would make is have the input type match the output type, but I don't know the use case of the method. Otherwise, it seems you're asking a question that only the author can really answer. There is no universal best practice for using `default` or explicitly returning `null`.  Also, if *"the magic number may be a negative number"*, then in that case you'd return the magic number.

Comment: FYI `null`, `default` & `default(int?)` seem to generate identical IL for `int?`.

Comment: If it is the case, default seems more like a syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would someone be changing the function signature? I recommend being explicit with types you know such as int, keeping it 0 so it's always 0 on default, no matter whether the int is wrapped in a Nullable struct. However, default becomes more useful when dealing with generics, where `default(T)` would return null for class generics and the default fielded struct for struct generics.
Essentially, my opinion is that it's not a good practice for things like this :)

Comment: The reason why the function signature is changed is because it needs to comply with the current convention in an old system (for example, using magic number -1 to represent null/non-existing). From my point of view, it is not a good reason, anyway. 

But I agree with you it is most useful in generics, where you may not know whether it is a primitive, reference or nullable struct type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's neither a good or bad practice.

It's worth remembering that default literal was [introduced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-7-1/#default-literals) to shorten `default(TypeNameHere)` and in the toy example shown you are right and typing `default` takes more key strokes than typing `default` and it seems unnecessary*.

As for '*when the return type of the function is changed from int? to int, it will return 0, which may be unintentional*', this argument works both ways.

Let's start with:

```
int TestDefault(int input)
{
    if (input > 10)
    {
        return input;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then, if the return type is changed to `int?` one could argue the method is incorrect (because the natural default for `int?` is null), and there would be no warning/error.

Ultimately, if you change return types you need to examine the method and adjust the code  accordingly.

---

As a small side note, the number of characters involved is not always what teams consider when choose coding standards even if the shorter version is entirely correct.
For example, many teams enforce having braces around `if`s even if there is only one statement:

```
if(x)
{
   DoOneThing();
}
```

vs

```
if(x)
   DoOneThing();
```

Please see [SA1503 Braces should not be omitted](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1503.md).

Comment: Nice point about "this argument works both ways.". You pointed out the other way around, which I overlooked.

Comment: Understand your point "the number of characters involved is not always what teams consider when choose coding standards". I am thinking, if both ways are more or less the same and serving the same purpose well, why I do not choose a way more specific and clear (that is, using 0 or null instead of default).